# How to get a single maven dependency's jar file copied to the dest dir?

Tags: maven, maven-bundle-plugin

I want to copy **com.X.Y.jar** to the desination directory **com/X/Z/target/distribution-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/bundle**.  The contents of this Jar file is used at runtime.

In **com.X.Z**'s pom file, I have the following dependency configuration

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.X</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.X.Y</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

However, it is not copied into the bundle directory like other dependencies appear to be.

How can I ensure that this dependency is copied correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not picking it automatically, can you use the dependency:copy-dependencies goal to put it where you want it?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

I'm not sure what you're referring to when you talk about a bundle directory.